# How can i split text like 1h 9 min to convert it like mm:ss like 69:00

Tags: php, time, preg-replace, preg-match, simple-html-dom

So i have a kind of script which grabs video from other website, and it's using simple_html_dom.

So basically i grab the page and later i extract data what i need from video. Im not stealing videos just trying to do it as faster than manually embeding videos.

So as part of page on that website there is a code like

```
<div class="videoTime">
    This is some video title
    <span> - 1h 9 min </span>
</div>
```

So i managed to extract text from inside a  so i get this at the end

```
- 1h 9 min
```

But i don't find the way to somehow convert this to minutes and seconds so i can have it displayed on my site like 69:00

Is there a way somehow to do this ?

Some way with preg_match and/or preg_replace, but im not very familiar with them?

Comment: Please add examples for 0h20min, 1h0min, 20min0secs...

Comment: there is no seconds, and when there are no hours it just shows min, and if it's exactly 1 hour it shows 1h 0 min.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for your initial example:

```
<?php
    preg_match ( '/[ \-]*([0-9]+)h[ ]*([0-9]+)[ ]*min/', $test, $matches );
    $hours = $matches[1];
    $minutes = $matches[2];
    echo $hours*60 + $minutes;
?>
```

**I couldn't perfect my regex, but this logic works if you leave out the hours input:

```
if(strpos($test, 'h') === FALSE) {
    $pattern = '/[ \-]*([0-9]+)[ ]*min/';
    preg_match ( $pattern, $test, $matches );
    $hours = 0;
    $minutes = $matches[1];

} else {
    $pattern = '/[ \-]*([0-9]+)h[ ]*([0-9]+)[ ]*min/';
    preg_match ( $pattern, $test, $matches );
    $hours = $matches[1];
    $minutes = $matches[2];
}
echo $hours*60 + $minutes;**
```

Comment: This kinda works, actually it works for the example i posted so i upvoted this, but when there's no hours i only get 19min for example. and than i get 0.

Comment: Use this regex instead in your first example `/(\d\d?) *h *(\d\d?) *min/i`... +1